How can I pass an instance of a class into that class's __init__ routine?
I have a QA development kit that allows you to create objects and override their properties and also the properties of their nested dependencies in one call:
An example:
class VendorCreateModel():  

    def __init__(self,

                registered_replacement_vendor_id: str | None = None,
                registered_replacement_vendor : VendorCreateModel | None = None,
                unregistered_vendor_retailer_id: str | None = None,
                unregistered_vendor_retailer: RetailerCreateModel | None = None,

                name: str | None = None,
                is_registered: str | None = None,
                contact_email: str | None = None,
                contact_phone: str | None = None,
                hq_city: str | None = None,
                hq_state: str | None = None,
                hq_country: str | None = None) -> None:
        
        
        self.name = name 
        self.registered_replacement_vendor_id = registered_replacement_vendor_id 
        self.registered_replacement_vendor = registered_replacement_vendor 
        self.unregistered_vendor_retailer_id = unregistered_vendor_retailer_id 
        self.unregistered_vendor_retailer = unregistered_vendor_retailer 
        self.is_registered = is_registered 
        self.contact_email = contact_email
        self.contact_phone = contact_phone
        self.hq_city = hq_city
        self.hq_state = hq_state
        self.hq_country = hq_country 

You'll note there are two referential ids, registered_replacement_vendor_id and unregistered_vendor_retailer_id. If the user provides these, great, that means they already created a registered_replacement_vendor and a unregistered_vendor_retailer and they want you to use those. If NOT, the QA Development Kit will create a default VendorCreateModel and RetailCreateModel and then let them use the registered_replacement_vendor and unregistered_vendor_retailer params to supply overrides (maybe they want to create an unregistered_vendor_retailer with a specific name for their test).
This all works really well everywhere except when one of the override params is of the same type as the CreateModel I'm creating, as is the case with registered_replacement_vendor.  This is of type VendorCreateModel, because it points to another Vendor that has been assigned to replace this one in our system.  Python does not like this, as it says "VendorCreateModel is not defined" on the line  registered_replacement_vendor : VendorCreateModel | None = None.
I understand why this is, but what is a good way to work around this? This pattern works fine in C# and Typescript, but python object creation is different. I'll have a few other relationships between objects of the same type so I want to make sure I follow a good pattern here so my team has a good foundation to build off of.
